Setting correct To-address when replying to forwarded message from Outlook
Microsoft MUAs (Outlook 365?) appear to forward emails while keeping the original From: address.  So if Joe forwards me an email by Jane, the email still appears as from Jane.  Instead, the forwarder's address is available in the Sender: field.
Is it possible for notmuch to detect this, and do the right thing when quoting (now it would quote Joe's additions with "Jane jane@example.com wrote:") and when replying (setting the To address to Joe and not to Jane)?
